# Microsoft Exchange emails not syncing with gmail app

Tags: sync, gmail, motorola-moto-g, outlook

I have a Moto g8 with Android 10. I use default gmail app to read my phone's gmail account as well as my two work emails (both MS Exchange/Outlook). I do not use the Outlook app for the latter.

I have all accounts on manual sync, by choice: they sync **only** when I open the app and push emails (swipe down). This works fine with the gmail account. However, since some time ago (maybe 6 months or more), the two MS accounts do not sync. I need to go to `Settings -> MS_account_name -> Incoming settings -> Next`, and then I get the emails. This lasts for a few hours. Then I need to repeat. It seems like MS authentication for Gmail app is temporary. I have all phone apps updated.

I've scrolled through lots of posts and webs but most advice is trivial ([example](https://www.lifewire.com/fix-email-not-working-android-7105728)) and not relevant. Can't find a reply to this specific problem. Any ideas?

Update: Has this anything to do with the [removal of basic auth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/deprecation-of-basic-authentication-exchange-online)?  I tried deleting and reinstalling app, as suggested [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/exchangeserver/comments/16170v8/android_gmail_app_and_exchange_hybrid_modern_auth/), but no effect so far.

Comment: As you have already set-up everything from scratch a bug in Gmail app could be the cause. To understand what is going wrong it may be helpful to check `adb logcat` messages when you try to sync and it fails. That requires to enable developer options on your phone and enable adb in it. On PC side you need an adb driver and at least the minimal adb package as I assume you don't have Android SDK installed.

Comment: @Robert Mmm, can I not dump the log as a file in the phone in a simpler way?

Comment: No. Apps don't have access to logs of other apps. `adb logcat` is the only way to get this kind of info on a non-rooted device. In general my recommendation is to have a working adb environment and a device that has granted adb permissions. Once you screen breaks adb is the only real option to get at least some your data form the phone (unless you sync everything to the cloud).